# What happens if I mark a question as 'no action needed' and it is found to be a duplicate later?

Tags: discussion, support

As the question says, what if it turns out to be a duplicate later? Will it impact negatively in any way towards my account or so?

Comment: @ivarni no I haven't failed any audit. Was just confirming if I  must check for duplicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding duplicates often requires some experience in the technology concerned. Reviewers are not expected to have that, so no you don't need to find whether the question is a duplicate.

If the question is clear, well written, on-topic then it's OK. If not then "no action needed" is the wrong choice.

The object of a review is to ensure that a question is one we're able to answer. If the mechanism that we later provide that answer is duplication then the question asker got their answer so everyone's happy.

Comment: NO the questions are perfect, have all necessary details and formatting. I just wanted to know if I am supposed to check for duplicate during reviewing

Comment: You did that's why accepted it. Maybe the question at the end confused you. Sorry for that...

Comment: *Reviewers are not expected to have that* I have heard the opposite from some people (maybe Cody?) in chat a few months ago. Whoever it was said that when an action to take isn't obvious, reviewers should skip posts they don't have enough expertise in to judge quite confidently. (Not that I think so too, that's just what someone said)

Comment: Nothing I've said contradicts the rule that if you're not confident then skip is the right answer. Duplicates are not always obvious, terminology may be different, examples vary etc.

Comment: If I said that, I wasn't really speaking with duplicate-finding in mind. More of, if you don't know a technology well enough to know whether the question contains a minimal, reproducible example, then that's a good time to Skip. If a Python programmer indicated that a Python question is problematic, thus putting it into a review queue, a non-Python programmer should not overrule their assessment lightly, as there may well be some problem that they missed due to lack of experience with the language. @CertainPerformance